# Adding an example to Doxygen generated Python documentation

Tags: python, doxygen

I am trying to add an example to the description of a Python class. It doesn't seem to work for some reason. The example is added to 'Example' tab on the generated HTML page just fine, but a link to the example is not shown in the description of the class. I have read the section in the doxygen manual covering the special command '@example' (http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdexample), but I still can't figure out how to do it right. It seems like no matter where I place the @example command, the link is not shown. I am using doxygen 1.8.5.

A simplified Python class where a link to an example should be shown:

```
class TestClass:

    ## The constructor.
    #  @param self The object pointer.
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = 0

    ## Stores a value.
    #  @param value The value to be stored.        
    def setValue(self, value):
        self.__value = value

    ## Gets stored value.
    #  @return The stored value.                
        def getValue(self):
        return self.__value

## @example TestClass_Example.py
#  This is an example of how to use TestClass
```

The example looks like this:

```
from TestClass import TestClass

def main():
    myTestClass = TestClass()
    myTestClass.setValue(37)
    print "The stored value is:", myTestClass.getValue()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Answers can be found [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#pythonblocks).

In short: You can´t use special commands (like example) using the python syntax of doxygen.
You have to use comments starting with `##` and then the special command.

> Note that in this case none of doxygen's special commands are
>   supported.
>
> There is also another way to document Python code using comments that
>   start with "##". These type of comment blocks are more in line with
>   the way documentation blocks work for the other languages supported by
>   doxygen and this also allows the use of special commands.

EDIT: Ahh sorry... just read that you already did this..

Are you sure that doxygen knows the Path to your file? Is it in the same directory?
Try setting the `EXAMPLE_PATH` in the doxygen config?

Comment: Actually I already added the example file directory to EXAMPLE_PATH in the config file, and given that the example is added to the 'Example' tab in the output HTML, I guess that this is not the issue.